# does connecting a Ethernet cable direct to a computer from a wireless router decrease the bandwidth?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

does connecting a Ethernet cable direct to a computer from a wireless router decrease the bandwidth thus disrupting or weakening the ability to connect to that wireless router harder for a cellphone or other device?

Comment: If it does, it's because the router is junk.

Comment: No it shoudn't.  Perhaps add a bit more detail about what is happening, and it will make it easier to find a diagnostic approach.

Comment: Decrease what bandwidth, between what and what?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not. If routers were designed so that wifi was impaired by a standard ethernet function half the models on the market would be completely useless.

In other words, No. Definitely not.

Edit> The functions itself shouldnt lead to decreased bandwidth. If the PC connected by ethernet is downloading or uploading stuff at high speed it could potentially affect the other users, But this is not as a result of their being an extra connection. This is a result of someone abusing the network.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean.

The plugged in computer will add an entry to the router's ARP table and DHCP lease table, which means that in principle traffic will be (very very slightly) slower as those larger tables are traversed (but not enough even to measure accurately).

The choke point in any realistic scenario is always the WAN connection, and obviously if the other computer is using a lot of traffic, that will slow things down.

So, a computer on the ethernet may add a nanosecond or so to packet switching times, but that difference will be completely lost in normal noise.

If you specifically mean "bandwidth" in the technical sense (the actual transfer bit rate), in principle that isn't affected at all, though I suppose the slightly larger ARP table leaves slightly less memory available for data transfer if the switching isn't done in hardware (but it often is).

Note that all of those examples apply just as much for a wireless client (moreso, in fact, since wireless line discipline is more complicated than ethernet's).

Answer (score 0):

Its not supposed to, however it can.

I have a setup where I had a consumer grade router with gigabit nics connected to a switch (with gigabit ports linked to each other).  When I sent traffic through one of the interfaces on the router (even though its on the same subnet and not being routed, it to another PC on the LAN), things went very slowly as obviously it was doing packet forwarding in software.   Moving the cables so as to use the switch and bypass the router for these PC's sped things up dramatically.

Theoretically this should not have been the case, but it definately was !!!